# Failed to change ownership of a file with permission 0666 in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, chown

OS: Linux. (CentOS 6)
Step 1: login as normal user and change the directory to the home directory
Step 2: su as root
Step 3: create a file and change permission to 0666
Step 4: change file ownership as normal user but failed

```
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$ pwd   
/home/belcon  
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$ su  
Password:   
[root@no1ca4sh belcon]# touch test.txt  
[root@no1ca4sh belcon]# echo "test">test.txt  
[root@no1ca4sh belcon]# cat test.txt  
test  
[root@no1ca4sh belcon]# chmod 666 test.txt  
[root@no1ca4sh belcon]# ls -l test.txt  
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5 Jun 26 17:50 test.txt  
[root@no1ca4sh belcon]# exit  
exit  
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$ ls -l test.txt  
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5 Jun 26 17:50 test.txt  
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$ chown belcon test.txt  
chown: changing ownership of `test.txt': Operation not permitted
```

That doesn't make sense since I can copy that file to another temporary file as normal user. That temporary file's owner is normal user. Then I can delete the original file, and make a copy the temporary file with same name as original file created by root user. It is actually what 'chown' want to do.

```
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$ cp test.txt test1.txt   
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$ ls -l test.txt test1.txt  
-rw-r--r-- 1 belcon wheel 5 Jun 26 17:56 test1.txt  
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root   root  5 Jun 26 17:50 test.txt 
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$ diff -Naur test1.txt test.txt   
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$ rm test.txt
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$ ls -l test.txt test1.txt   
ls: cannot access test.txt: No such file or directory  
-rw-r--r-- 1 belcon wheel 5 Jun 26 17:56 test1.txt   
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$ cp test1.txt test.txt   
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$ ls -l test.txt test1.txt  
-rw-r--r-- 1 belcon wheel 5 Jun 26 17:56 test1.txt  
-rw-r--r-- 1 belcon wheel 5 Jun 26 17:57 test.txt   
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$ diff -Naur test1.txt test.txt   
[belcon@no1ca4sh ~]$
```

Can anyone please to explain why I couldn't change ownership of a file with permission 0666? Does there exist some reasons for that?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary users can't `chown` files.

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27350/why-cant-a-normal-user-chown-a-file

Basically, it would allow users to evade quotas, and there are other edge cases where security can be compromised. (e.g. applications assuming root-owned files are secure, because only root could have written them).